# force a ceiling to count(*) in sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using a subquery to return a count as an integer value to my main query.  This query is used to rebind an ASP.NET DataGrid and I have only two characters width available for this column.  I want to restrict the width to two characters.  So, I want to set a value of 99 when the count exceeds 99.  I can't figure a way to do this?  I can't see how to apply a case statement here.

```
SELECT
     MEMB_ID,
     MEMB_Name,
     SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM SessionOrder
WHERE SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = m.MEMB_ID 
  And SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0
     As MEMB_Downloads,
     MEMB_JoinDate
FROM Member
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you sure that your current query is valid?

Comment: I left out a few details but enough to show what I am attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE expression can look like this:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 99 THEN 99 ELSE COUNT(*) END
```

There appear to be a couple of errors with your existing query (for example `m` is not defined). With these errors corrected and the above change made the resulting query could look like this:

```
SELECT
     MEMB_ID,
     MEMB_Name,
     (
         SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 99 THEN 99 ELSE COUNT(*) END
         FROM SessionOrder
         WHERE SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = MEMB_ID 
         AND SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0
     ) AS MEMB_Downloads,
     MEMB_JoinDate
FROM Member
```

Comment: Ok, so I will have to actually perform the subquery twice in order to do this?  I was hoping to avoid that but maybe I have no choice?

Comment: @Jim: Why do you need to perform the subquery twice?

Comment: I shall give that a go!  Looks like a winner!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I hadn't realized COUNT(*) could be referenced twice like that, cool stuff.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
COUNT(*)
```

With

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 99 THEN 99 ELSE COUNT(*) END AS YourColumnName
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit more efficient. As it can stop scanning rows once the 99th is reached.

```
SELECT MEMB_ID  ,
       MEMB_Name,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM    ( 
               SELECT TOP 99 * 
               FROM SessionOrder
               WHERE   SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = MEMB_ID
               AND     SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0
               )
               Top99
       ) AS MEMB_Downloads,
       MEMB_JoinDate
FROM   Member
```

Comment: Martin, thank you for the limit.  Yes, this should be better.

Comment: "SELECT TOP 99 *": select the Id only, or something, do not waste processor. (If you're lucky the system will guess that for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change the COUNT(*) result, better count at most 99:

```
SELECT
     MEMB_ID,
     MEMB_Name,
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM (
        SELECT TOP(99) *
        FROM SessionOrder
        WHERE SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = m.MEMB_ID 
        And SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0)
       as TOP99_Downloads)
     As MEMB_Downloads,
     MEMB_JoinDate
FROM Member;
```

This way you avoid counting all the downloads when you'll only display 99 anyway. Of course, one would ask what is the point of displaying a value if is incorrect to start with and why not make your UI layer capable of displaying 'more than 99'.

Comment: Thank you, this limit makes sense.  I have several of those counters in a datagrid with very limited space available.  My client wants way too much info on a single page.  Not how I would want it either!  Thanks

Comment: @ANeves: Actually `*` is the best option. With `*` the COUNT operator above is free to count *any* column, and the query optimizer will choose the column that can be counted using the most narrow possible index.

Comment: Actually my previous comment is wrong, thanks @Remus Rusanu. [Previous comment removed.] * is the best option, and counting a particular column instead of * might even yield unexpected results if there were nulls (not counted).

Answer (score 0):

CASE it should be ...

Answer (score 0):

or double UNION as
    SELECT
         MEMB_ID,
         MEMB_Name,
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS WC
     FROM SessionOrder
    WHERE SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = m.MEMB_ID 
      And SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0
      And WC =< 99
         As MEMB_Downloads,
         MEMB_JoinDate
     FROM Member
UNION
   SELECT
        MEMB_ID,
        MEMB_Name,
        99 AS WC
    FROM SessionOrder
   WHERE SessionOrder.SORD_MEMB_ID = m.MEMB_ID 
     And SessionOrder.SORD_NumberCompleteDownloads <> 0
     And WC > 99
        As MEMB_Downloads,
        MEMB_JoinDate
   FROM Member